# GET request returning different result in different browsers

Tags: api, reddit

I'm having a problem with API requests giving inconsistent results.

I'm trying to send the following request to the Reddit API: https://www.reddit.com/search.json?q=url:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7Sf_H2cFdM. This should return a list of all threads that link to that video specified by the url, of which there should be two (I checked manually). However, I don't get any threads returned at all.

[Chrome Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UimZm.png)

I thought it might be just a bug with the Reddit API that I couldn't fix, but then I tried the same request across different browsers. As it turns out, the request does return the correct results, but strangely only in Firefox Developer Edition.

[Firefox Developer Edition Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGH8a.png)

I have no idea why the results are different, and my only guess is that it might be because the request headers are different, but even still, I don't know how that would change anything. If anyone has any guess as to what might be causing this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine anyone actually running into the same problem in the future, but if that's you, u/ketralnis on reddit left an awesome reply in an r/bugs thread that explains the issue and a solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/bugs/comments/7d0hg0/inconsistent_reddit_api_results/